# When is a contract constructor called?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

From this [solidity doc](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html) I know that the constructor is called once when the contract is created. But are there other instances that the constructor is called?

I am looking for all possible cases that the constructor of a contract will be called to better understand the use of a constructor in smart contracts and the consequences of not having a constructor.

Answer (score 7):

No. As it say in the docs, constructor is called only once.

> When a contract is created, its constructor (a function declared with the constructor keyword) is executed once.

It would be a huge security breach if it could be called more than once, since constructor usually sets up contract ownership and other important variables.

[Parity hack](https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/on-the-parity-wallet-multisig-hack-405a8c12e8f7) happened exactly because it was possible to call the "constructor" multiple times using `delegatecall`.